# Entity Framework - referencing ID twice

Tags: entity-framework

I am new to EF, I just have a simple question. I already know how to have one-to-many relationship. but my question is this. Say I have 2 tables: `QuestionPool` and `AnswerPool`.

- `QuestionPool` has `QuesID`, `Question` columns
- `AnswerPool` has `AnsID`, `QuesID`, `Answer`, `NextQuesID`

My problem is: `QuesID` and `NextQuesID` will be coming from the `QuestionPool` and both will have the `QuesID` for reference. How can I use `QuesID` twice as reference?

Thanks,
Gilbert

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
   var results = (from q in QuestionPool
                join a in AnswerPool on q.QuesID equals a.QuesID
                select new {
                    QuesID = q.QuesID,
                    AnswerQuesID = a.QuesID,
                    a.AnsID,
                    a.NextQuesID
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks for the fast reply.... sorry i did not specify clearly my goal... on the answers Page... if i click create, I would have dropdown on QuesID and NextQuesID, both of them should have the list of the QuesID on QuestionPool.